# ASP.NET Core. Использование контроллера в качестве сервиса

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет. Имеется контроллер, который я бы хотел использовать как сервис.
Он содержит методы, которые обрабатывают данные/LINQ-запросы.
И теперь я бы хотел подключаться к нему из других контроллеров, не используя RedirectToAction и.т.п. Как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: А зачем? Почему бы просто вынести логику в отдельный класс и потом резолвить через контейнер зависимостей.

Comment: Обычно стараются контроллеры делать тонкими, содержащими только вызовы классов бизнес-логики. Вынесите логику в отдельные классы, вызывайте из нужных мест. Вы сами говорите что вы "используете контроллеры *в качестве сервиса*". Логику - в сервис, вызов - в контроллер.

Comment: Дело в том, что методы в контроллере содержат объект Request. И также, я хотел бы методом, содержащимся в данном классе, возвращать результат в методах контроллера.

Comment: Контроллер - это просто способ вызвать вашу бизнес логику по http, они должны быть максимально простыми, потому если вам надо что то переиспользовать - переиспользуйте вашу бизнес логику, а не контроллеры.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Я все-таки сменил логику, не затрагивая при этом контроллеры.

Answer (score 0):

Я создал отдельный метод загрузки данных для компонента. Сделал таким образом:

*Метод для загрузки данных*

```
public static object Load<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, HttpRequest request) where T : class
{
    ***
}
```

*Вызов в контроллере*

```
public IActionResult GetData() {
    var obj = *Коллекция объектов*
    return Ok(Data.Load(obj));
}
```